# Why does this C implementation of heapsort give segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, heapsort

I tried executing this code in gcc as well as turboc. In GCC it gives me a segmentation fault error at run time and in turbo it gives a null pointer assignment error again at run time.

I tried tracing it but i cant see where the problem is.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int heapsize;

void heapify(int a[],int i)
{
    int l=2*i,r=2*i+1,largest,temp;
    if(l<=heapsize && a[l]>a[i])
        largest=l;
    else
        largest=i;
    if(r<=heapsize && a[r]>a[largest])
        largest=r;
    if(largest!=i)
    {
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[largest];
        a[largest]=temp;
        heapify(a,largest);
    }
}

void buildheap(int a[],int length)
{
    int i;  
    heapsize=length;    
    for(i=length/2;i>=0;i--)
        heapify(a,i);
}

void heapsort(int a[],int length)
{
    int i,temp; 
    buildheap(a,length);
    for(i=length-1;i>=1;i++)
    {
        temp=a[0];
        a[0]=a[i];
        a[i]=temp;
        heapsize--;         
        heapify(a,0);   
    }
}

void main()
{
    int a[20],i,length;
    printf("ENTER THE SIZE OF YOUR ARRAY:");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    printf("ENTER THE ARRAY ELEMENTS: \n");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    heapsort(a,length);
    printf("THE SORTED ARRAY IS:");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        printf("%d /t",a[i]);
}
```

NOTE: I coded this using the heapsort algorithm given in CLRS.

Edit: here's the input i gave and the error I got.

> chaitanya@chaitanya-laptop:~/Desktop/My prog$ ./a.out
>   ENTER THE SIZE OF YOUR ARRAY:5
>   ENTER THE ARRAY ELEMENTS:
>   9
>   5
>   8
>   7
>   6
>   Segmentation fault

**Edit:** apparently a silly mistake of i++ instead of i-- was causing the problem. but now there seems to be a logical error since the program is not giving the sorted array as the output.

> ENTER THE SIZE OF YOUR ARRAY:5
>   ENTER THE ARRAY ELEMENTS:
>   2
>   4
>   3
>   1
>   9
>   THE SORTED ARRAY IS:3013077   4   1   9   2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following for loop will never terminate. The index keeps on increasing causing array to go out of bounds and that's the reason you get the above error.

```
for(i=length-1;i>=1;i++)
{
    temp=a[0];
    a[0]=a[i];
    a[i]=temp;
    heapsize--;         
    heapify(a,0);   
}
```

Update : Your heapify() is incorrect.. try this instead

```
if(l<heapsize && a[l]>a[i])
    largest=l;
else
    largest=i;
if(r<heapsize && a[r]>a[largest])
    largest=r;
```

Comment: okay that cleared out the segmentation fault but apparently there is a logical error in my program. For an input of: (2, 4, 3, 1, 9) i am getting an output of: (3013077, 4, 1, 9, 2)

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem - I have updated the answer.. to answer your edit.

Comment: -another error i discovered from someone's help was that since the index starts from 0, l and r should be initialized as l=2*i+1 and r=2*i+2.

Answer (score 0):

- If the user inputs a `length` greater than 20 you most assuredly will overflow `a`
- The `heapsort` function never terminates because `i` keeps *growing*.  You should have `i--` instead.
- The `printf` at the end outputs `/t`, not a tab.  Change it to `\t`

These should at least get you past the segfault, though the sorting still doesn't look correct.

Comment: gave very simple inputs. i edited the question. you can check it out.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem: And the error you are getting, especially if it contains a line number.

Comment: it doesnt contain a line number. Its a run time error. NOT a compile time error.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem: I guess this is C we're talking about.  Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: Yes this is C we are talking about. And no i have not tried running it in a debugger yet. I will do it now

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem: Alright, found the segfault.  The answer still isn't right, but that (and using a debugger) should get you farther at least.

Comment: do you see where the error is? i am drawing a blank.

Comment: @ChaitanyaNettem: Separate question, really.  You asked about the segfault, and we answered it.  You should open another question and accept one of the answers here.

Comment: yea...i did that now. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `heapsort` function, you should use `i--` instead of `i++` in the `for` loop.

Comment: okay that cleared out the segmentation fault but apparently there is a logical error in my program. For an input of: (2, 4, 3, 1, 9) i am getting an output of: (3013077, 4, 1, 9, 2)